# Changing the button background alternatively

Tags: android

I have an android project where i need to use a switch.
I am using a Button for this.
I have two images one for on state and another for off state. Initially i am giving "off_image" as background of Button. When the user clicks the button the background should change to "on_image" and when again the user clicks it should change back to "off_image".

I am using the below code but it is not working....

Inside onClick method --->

```
if(button.getBackground().equals(R.drawable.off_image)
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.on_image);
if(button.getBackground().equals(R.drawable.on_image)
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.off_image);
```

Please treat me as a novice and give detailed solution.

Thank you.

Comment: I think it should be R.drawable.off_image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, save a global var lastImageResource.

```
int lastImageResource= R.id.off_image;
```

now, each time you switch background update it like this:

```
if(lastImageResource  == (R.id.off_image)){
        button.setImageResource(R.id.on_image);
        lastImageResource = R.id.on_image;
}
if(lastImageResource  == (R.id.on_image)){
        button.setImageResource(R.id.off_image);
        lastImageResource = R.id.off_image;
}
```

Now it should work.

Comment: I just tried setBackgroundResource but it is also not working.

Comment: I think the problem is with getBackground()

Comment: Could be it, did you try debug it and see if it reach that point?

Answer (score 0):

Use getConstantState()

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    drawableDownloaded=holder.iv_catch_status.getDrawable().getConstantState() == context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cloud_download).getConstantState();
                }else{
                    drawableDownloaded=holder.iv_catch_status.getDrawable().getConstantState() == context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cloud_download).getConstantState();
                }
```

and to set image

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                this.statusImage.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play));
            }else{
                this.statusImage.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

How come you are using `R.id.image`.

These are drawables, use `R.drawable.image`.

Also,

You are setting, `ImageResource`, but check background.
Both are different things.

Why don't you just use `boolean`?

`boolean isOn = false`

And, then toggle it.

Comment: Sorry that was a typing mistake.In my code i have used drawable

Answer (score 0):

Compare the constant states and use `setBackgroundResource()` as follows:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (button.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera).getConstantState())){
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
            }
            else if(button.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery).getConstantState())){
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
            }
        }
    });
```

If `minSdkVersion` is less than 21 use `getResources().getDrawable()` instead of the `getDrawable()` method.

Comment: It worked fine but there is a message which says "  getDrawable(int) is deprecated  " does this warning matter...?

Comment: It says that the method is discouraged from using by google as it may be dangerous or less secure and an alternative usually exists. Use ContextCompat.getDrawable() method instead. Change the code as _button.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_menu_camera).getConstantState())_.